# SQL Query with condition IF on reported fields

Tags: sql, database, if-statement

I've had a look around and have found example queries where the IF forms part of the record selection, but I want it to form part of what is output.

Basically I have a table of products which includes a manufacturer id and part id as well as a unique record number.  Many of the products have a barcode, but not all.  What I want to do is create a query to list all of the products, but where there is no barcode generate a barcode for internal use based on the unique record number.  It doesn't need to be a valid barcode for external purposes, so I'm not bothered about the check digit generation.  I've done something similar in Excel years ago, but can't work out how I do the IF bit in an SQL query.  The following is an example of what I'd like to do, but the syntax isn't right:

```
SELECT manufacturerID, partID, if(barcode is blank, "5000000"+unqueID, barcode)
FROM products
```

I've seen CASE statements mentioned, but couldn't get my head around how it would fit in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just worried about null values, something like NVL (oracle) or ISNULL (mysql) can help

```
SELECT manufacturerID, partID, NVL(barcode, "5000000"+uniqueID) FROM products;
```

If your comparison is scalar, then decode can help as well

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php

```
SELECT  manufacturerID, partID,
        DECODE (barcode, '',    5000000+uniqueID, barcode) result
FROM suppliers;
```

or finally you always have case, mother of all

```
select manufacturerID, partID,
    CASE 
         WHEN barcode = '' THEN "5000000" + uniqueID 
         ELSE barcode 
    END
from products
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies - all of you spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT manufacturerID, partID,
    CASE 
         WHEN barcode = '' OR barcode IS NULL 
         THEN "5000000" + unqueID 
         ELSE barcode 
    END
FROM products
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`CASE`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210728081626/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml) statement has syntax like this:

```
SELECT manufacturerID, 
  partID, 
  case 
    when barcode is null or barcode = ''
    then '5000000'+unqueID
    else barcode
  end as barcode
FROM products;
```